# Компиляция методов в шаблонном классе в зависимости от параметра шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Хочу написать шаблонный класс, который будет получать в качестве параметра шаблона другой шаблонный класс.

Проблема в том, что среди шаблонов, которые будут параметрами, есть различные классы, которые имеют несколько отличающийся интерфейс и поэтому при компиляции возможны ошибки из-за несоответствия интерфейсов.

Как, например, ниже:

```
#include <memory>

template <class T> class FirstCreator
{
public:
    typedef T object_type;

    T* GetNewObject()
    {
        T* pT = new T();
        return pT;
    }
};

template <class T> class SecondCreator
{
public:
    typedef T object_type;

    std::shared_ptr<T> GetNewObjectEx()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> pT;
        return pT;
    }
};

template <class TCreator> class CreatorUser
{
public:
    TCreator* m_pData;

    CreatorUser(TCreator& data)
    {
        m_pData = &data;
    }

    typename TCreator::object_type* GetNewObjectPtr()
    {
        return m_pData->GetNewObject();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<typename TCreator::object_type> GetNewObjectSharedPtr()
    {
        return m_pData->GetNewObjectEx();
    }

    void SimpleFunction()
    {
        //Здесь на самом деле нужен вызов только одной фукнции:
        //GetNewObjectPtr, если параметр шаблона FirstCreator
        //GetNewObjectSharedPtr, если параметр шаблона SecondCreator
        //но как дать понять компилятору это?
        typename TCreator::object_type* pObj = GetNewObjectPtr();
        delete pObj;

        std::shared_ptr<typename TCreator::object_type> pObjShared = GetNewObjectSharedPtr();
    }
};

typedef FirstCreator<int> IntCreatorFirst;
typedef SecondCreator<int> IntCreatorSecond;

int main()
{
    IntCreatorFirst creator1;
    IntCreatorSecond creator2;

    CreatorUser<IntCreatorFirst>* pCreatorUser1 = new CreatorUser<IntCreatorFirst>(creator1);
    CreatorUser<IntCreatorSecond>* pCreatorUser2 = new CreatorUser<IntCreatorSecond>(creator2);

    pCreatorUser1->SimpleFunction();
    pCreatorUser2->SimpleFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

При попытке вызвать SimpleFunction компилятор выдает ошибку

> Error 1   error C2039: 'GetNewObjectEx' : is not a member of
>   'FirstCreator'

Что совершенно справедливо, так как такой функции у `FirstCreator` действительно нет.

Мне нужно написать `SimpleFunction` таким образом, чтобы если параметром `CreatorUser` является `FirstCreator`, то вызывался метод `GetNewObjectPtr`, а метод `GetNewObjectSharedPtr` вообще не создавался и наоборот.

Есть ли в C++ возможность сделать подобное?

UPD:

Исправил в соответствии с первым ответом, заработало. Пришлось правда завернуть функции в другую функцию - но тут, наверное, проблема старого компилятора (компилятор студии MS VS 2010), который все время ругался, что функция не может иметь шаблонных параметров по умолчанию:

```
void SimpleFunctionEx()
{
    SimpleFunction<TCreator>();
}

template<typename TCreator>
void SimpleFunction(typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<TCreator, FirstCreator<typename TCreator::object_type> >::value>::type* = nullptr)
{
    typename TCreator::object_type* pObj = GetNewObjectPtr();
    delete pObj;
}

template<typename TCreator>
void SimpleFunction(typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<TCreator, SecondCreator<typename TCreator::object_type> >::value>::type* = nullptr)
{
    std::shared_ptr<typename TCreator::object_type> pObjShared = GetNewObjectSharedPtr();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```
template<typename U = TCreator>
void SimpleFunction(typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, FirstCreator>::value>::type* = nullptr)
{
    // Используем GetNewObjectPtr.
}

template<typename U = TCreator>
void SimpleFunction(typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, SecondCreator>::value>::type* = nullptr)
{
    // Используем GetNewObjectSharedPtr.
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ, это воспользоваться специализацией шаблона:

```
template <class TCreator> 
class CreatorUser;

template<>
class CreatorUser<FirstCreator>
{
public:
    FirstCreator* m_pData;

    CreatorUser(FirstCreator& data)
    {
        m_pData = &data;
    }

    FirstCreator::object_type* GetNewObjectPtr()
    {
        return m_pData->GetNewObject();
    }

    void SimpleFunction()
    {
        FirstCreator::object_type* pObj = GetNewObjectPtr();
        delete pObj;
    }
};

template<>
class CreatorUser<SecondCreator>
{
public:
    SecondCreator* m_pData;

    CreatorUser(SecondCreator& data)
    {
        m_pData = &data;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<SecondCreator::object_type> GetNewObjectSharedPtr()
    {
        return m_pData->GetNewObjectEx();
    }

    void SimpleFunction()
    {
        std::shared_ptr<SecondCreator::object_type> pObjShared = GetNewObjectSharedPtr();
    }
};
```

Код я не проверял, поэтому могут быть опечатки, но суть должна быть ясна.